# $\int f^{-1}(\frac{1}{x}) dx $, where $f^{-1}$ is inverse function.

Tags: soft-question, lambert-w, tetration

**I had to changed orginal question because I was too edgy with my different questionsand I can't ask another one**

It can by showed that $\int f^{-1}(x) dx=xf^{-1}(x)-F \circ f^{-1}(x)+C$

Is there exists some general solution for $\int f^{-1}(\frac{1}{x}) dx $

Comment: I doubt that we can solve this way exercises with more entries in the power tower like $x\uparrow \uparrow 5=2$

Comment: And the purpose of tetration mainly was to produce huge numbers. I do not think that there is any useful extension for $x\uparrow \uparrow n$ for the case that $n$ is a non-integer.

Comment: You never know. Maybe it's hiding something important

Comment: @Wreior You can replace any $q$ by $x^q$.

Comment: I know, but it's seems to be not effective after tetration IV. I mean. It give nasty results

Comment: But you give me some idea. What about making it as infinite power tower and trying to find some generalisation betwin gaps of tetrations of natural order

Comment: I guess we can only combine the bottom levels and the top levels of the q: Define $^nq$. $\ \ \ ^{n+1}q=\left(x^q\right)^{\left(^nq\right)}=x^{\left(^nq\cdot q\right)}=x^{q^{\left(^{n-1}q+1\right)}}$. And we can replace any $q$ by $x^q$.

Comment: Another view at the LambertW-expression of yours can be written as $$q=\exp(-W(-\log(x))) \qquad .$$ *(Check whether this solves to the same value as your first equation.)* 
This way to write it suggests to use it in an iteration itself: 
$$ r=\exp(-W(-W(-\log(x)))) \qquad .$$ 
With this 
    $$\left(1/r^{1/r}\right) ^{\left(r^{1/r}\right)}  = x $$
Or $$ r=\exp(W(W(-\log(x)))) \qquad .$$ 
Then $$ \left(1/r^r\right)^{(r^r)} = x $$ ... and so on. 
If you are exploring the LambertW for such a problem-class, you might even iterate further and see, whether there is something interesting.

Comment: So, changing the question invalidates all of the comments from last February?  Why not ask a new question?

Comment: Because I can't. I made a lot of bad questions and I can't add new one

Comment: Now consider this with $f(x) = \log(x)$.  Then $\int f(x)\,dx$ and $\int f(1/x)\,dx$ are both elementary functions, but $\int f^{-1}(1/x)\,dx = \int\exp(1/x)\,dx$ is not elementary.  So I conckude  that there is no nice formula for $\int f^{-1}(1/x)\,dx$ of this kind.

Comment: Apply [integral of inverse function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_inverse_functions) with $f^{-1}(x)\to f^{-1}(\frac1x)$. You would need to know $F=\int \frac{dx}{f(x)}$ instead of $F=\int f(x)dx$ then.